# Method takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, celery, args

I'm running a celery task, which needs two arguments, like so:

```
@task_bp.route('/analysis/<user_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def save_user_with_analysis(user_id):

    post_data = request.get_json()

    response_object = {
        'status': 'fail',
        'message': 'User does not exist'
    }
    spotify_token = ''

    if post_data:
        spotify_token = post_data.get('spotify_token')
    try:
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
        if not user:
            return jsonify(response_object), 404
        else:
             # pass 2 args, ID and token 
             task = save_user_tracks_with_analysis.apply_async(args=[user_id, spotify_token],kwargs={})

            response_object = {
                'status': 'success',
                'message': 'Background task for saving user analysis to database initialized.',
                'data': {
                    'task_id': task.id,
                }
            }
            return jsonify(response_object), 202
    except (exc.IntegrityError, ValueError):
        db.session.rollback()
        return jsonify(response_object), 404
```

and:

```
@celery.task(queue='analysis',default_retry_delay=30,max_retries=3,soft_time_limit=1000)
def save_user_tracks_with_analysis(user_id, spotify_token):
    track_and_features = sp_utilities.query_tracks(spotify_token)
    try:    
        while True:
            result = Upload_Track_With_Audio_Analysis(dataset=next(track_and_features), 
                                                      user_id=user_id)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    finally:
        del track_and_features 

    return {'Status': 'Tracks uploaded with analysis!'}
```

but I get this error:

> TypeError: save_user_tracks_with_analysis() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Full Traceback:

```
[2019-10-23 00:38:58,444: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis[d0db40ee-a1bb-4dbb-b066-7db9b5f5900d]  
[2019-10-23 00:38:58,450: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x7f5d8a9448c8> (args:('project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis', 'd0db40ee-a1bb-4dbb-b066-7db9b5f5900d', {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'brandio.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis', 'id': 'd0db40ee-a1bb-4dbb-b066-7db9b5f5900d', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, 1000], 'root_id': 'd0db40ee-a1bb-4dbb-b066-7db9b5f5900d', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': "['1', '']", 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen14@9065a884289a', 'reply_to': '4ed9cf27-826d-3d3d-9282-83750953189b', 'correlation_id': 'd0db40ee-a1bb-4dbb-b066-7db9b5f5900d', 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'analysis', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': None}}, b'[["1", ""], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]', 'application/json', 'utf-8') kwargs:{})
[2019-10-23 00:38:58,457: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis[d0db40ee-a1bb-4dbb-b066-7db9b5f5900d] pid:12
[2019-10-23 00:38:58,456: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis[d0db40ee-a1bb-4dbb-b066-7db9b5f5900d] raised unexpected: TypeError('save_user_tracks_with_analysis() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: save_user_tracks_with_analysis() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[2019-10-23 00:40:10,528: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis[a049f85f-bb5a-4cf3-81f8-f334210cb7e4]  
[2019-10-23 00:40:10,532: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x7f5d8a9448c8> (args:('project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis', 'a049f85f-bb5a-4cf3-81f8-f334210cb7e4', {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis', 'id': 'a049f85f-bb5a-4cf3-81f8-f334210cb7e4', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, 1000], 'root_id': 'a049f85f-bb5a-4cf3-81f8-f334210cb7e4', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': "['1', 'BQCFoIPB1BS3_Fe4nrHuTJMJ2bDDqOJBlEMH2-TwzrAeLk8GN30O3DQm3hRW2DRFVbaDb-0msctmjN6phKAmad4F6hs9AilCyyO_Ky5JoT1cThsRNoL6GptRh1SPcYL29toTkUQitXcRSaDRQY0BsJB9haNtCRD-KNhNPQSC0dbCB6M-tWBd-4l9hl74tRR7csamu5qBol653QBfoNhcKzvJeSaewPMpyhMArvA_DW4Pcr8KLFsFmEV8jiDb2d0f']", 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen14@9065a884289a', 'reply_to': '4ed9cf27-826d-3d3d-9282-83750953189b', 'correlation_id': 'a049f85f-bb5a-4cf3-81f8-f334210cb7e4', 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'analysis', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': None}}, b'[["1",... kwargs:{})
[2019-10-23 00:40:10,536: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis[a049f85f-bb5a-4cf3-81f8-f334210cb7e4] pid:13
[2019-10-23 00:40:10,537: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis[a049f85f-bb5a-4cf3-81f8-f334210cb7e4] raised unexpected: TypeError('save_user_tracks_with_analysis() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: save_user_tracks_with_analysis() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[2019-10-23 01:45:54,209: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis[7391e3c7-ddf9-4f76-a046-36506b3c8289]  
[2019-10-23 01:45:54,212: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x7f5d8a9448c8> (args:('project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis', '7391e3c7-ddf9-4f76-a046-36506b3c8289', {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis', 'id': '7391e3c7-ddf9-4f76-a046-36506b3c8289', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, 1000], 'root_id': '7391e3c7-ddf9-4f76-a046-36506b3c8289', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': "('1', 'BQABvl5STugFWzHizIipkw0B7-_g7MmP-lFAokVh4_XMJFHGl6XYNmEvi8AieQduMxpqHCujjkOJC4sypY4w-7_77NSsspXUpVn65bW77VeyihG5JLmJpIC86pqzzijZZTZfu-RTt1_yBCkK7UXsEb1K7biWcL8gpVsfZu1vAsFsI1V51IP3sxKoXf3ohPxTLddH1Wfi_npfOv1wkgaeLdbwxCaO2gEqowqRappzIiSNfXqCSAIdNNaGPROqpR5r')", 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen30@9065a884289a', 'reply_to': '5b96d61f-e2f9-3237-a7a1-afab83d41e12', 'correlation_id': '7391e3c7-ddf9-4f76-a046-36506b3c8289', 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'analysis', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': None}}, b'[["1",... kwargs:{})
[2019-10-23 01:45:54,214: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis[7391e3c7-ddf9-4f76-a046-36506b3c8289] pid:12
[2019-10-23 01:45:54,225: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task project.api.routes.background.save_user_tracks_with_analysis[7391e3c7-ddf9-4f76-a046-36506b3c8289] raised unexpected: TypeError('save_user_tracks_with_analysis() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: save_user_tracks_with_analysis() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

as far as I'm concerned, `apply_sync()` needs args to be passed as `list`.

what am I missing?

Comment: The way I see it, the method takes two, and I’m passing two.

Comment: My guess is the @celery.task decorator in the line above the save_user_tracks_with_analysis definition is redefining what save_user_tracks_with_analysis does.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb right, and that’s the reason I’m asking what’s wrong with the working code

Comment: https://pawelzny.com/python/celery/2017/08/14/celery-4-tasks-best-practices/ - as the example shows the args are passed as tuple.

Comment: either tuple or list throw the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using the `kwargs` parameter instead of `args` in the `apply_async()` call?

Comment: yes. have also tried using `delay()`, instead of `apply_sync()`. não rola.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why, but when I restarted the Docker app, and all celery workers, the code above started working.

Comment: Most likely the worker was running the old code, where the function had just one parameter... Your client had the new code and tried to run it, but the worker still had the old code and failed. This is a common scenario, and that is probably why it started to work when you restarted the worker.